# Matching wrong Extension method

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, extension-methods

I have these Extension methods:

```
public static void Replace<T>(this IList list, T newItem)

public static void Replace<T>(this IList<T> list, IEnumerable newItems)

public static void Replace<T>( this IList<T> list, IEnumerable<T> newItems )
```

I have a Linq statement that produces an `IList<IWell>` called, wells.  (I confirm at runtime that wells is `IEnumerable<IWell>`.)

However, the statement

```
SelectedValues.Replace( wells );
```

always hits the first extension method, not the second or third.  (I confirm at runtime that SelectedValues is `IList<IWell>`.)

Is it obvious what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the declared type of `SelectedValues` and of `wells`? Extension methods are bound at compile-time, not at runtime so it is the compile-time types that matter.

Edit: Since you said that `SelectedValues` is declared as type `IList`, the only possible candidate for use as an extension method on `SelectedValues` of the three you provided is

```
public static void Replace<T>(this IList list, T newItem)
```

The compiler then realizes that it can consider `wells` as a `T` with `T` being the declared type of `wells` and then can invoke the method

```
public static void Replace<T>(this IList list, T newItem)
```

where `SelectedValues` fills in for the parameter `list` and `wells` fills in for the parameter `newItem`, and the declared type of `wells` fills in for the type parameter `T`. This is why that extension method is invoked.

Again, extension methods are bound at compile-time. If you want to invoke a different method, you need to use a different declared type for `SelectedValues`.

So, this is not a case of the compiler "Matching wrong Extension method," this is a case of the compiler matching the only possible extension method. This behavior is by design; it is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: SelectedValues is declared as IList.

Comment: @Kelly: Then you have your answer right there. Since it's declared as type `IList`, the only candidate extension method is `public static void Replace<T>(this IList list, T newItem)`. The other two are never even considered by the compiler. I'll elaborate a bit in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember the rules for overload preference, but as a solution, specifying a (superfluous) cast usually fixes these:

```
SelectedValues.Replace((IEnumerable<IWell>)wells);
```

Comment: When you get a compile-time warning, do you use a `#pragma` to disable, or do you seek out the root cause?

Comment: @Jason: I'm sure somebody who's better-educated than me on this will post an answer detailing *why* this happens.

Comment: This works, after I added a new method, public static void Replace<T>( this IList list, IEnumerable<T> newItems ) and since I wells is local, I changed it's declaration from IList<IWell> to IEnumerable<IWell>.  That works, too, without the cast.  So, all the parameter types have to match exactly, without regard for which classes they inherit or which interfaces they implement?

Comment: @Kelly: Please see my answer for _why_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855465/matching-wrong-extension-method/4855538#4855538.

Comment: Thank you Matti; your answer got me going, then Jason filled in the "why".

Answer (score 0):

The interesting type here is not `SelectedValues`, but `wells` - which of `T`, `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` is it? If you always hit the first method, it is likely that `wells`, despite the plural form of it's name, is just a single `T` instance.

Also, it would be nice to know *exactly* what type `SelectedValues` is - the fact that it implements `IList<IWell>` doesn't stop it from implementing `IList` as well.

Comment: wells is IList<IWell> and I am making sure that it always has multiple items.